# PyX Preamble Disabled with no previous calls

Tags: python-2.7, pyx

I'm using PyX 0.12.1 to produce an EPS document for printing. I'm following the example in the [documentation](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/examples/text/font.html) for changing the font, and have the following:

```
from pyx import *
text.set("Latex")
text.preamble(r"\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}")
height = 37 * unit.mm
c = canvas.canvas()
c.text(0, 15*unit.mm, "Hello, World!", [text.parbox(height), text.halign.boxcenter, text.halign.flushcenter])
```

When testing from my PC, this works as expected, however when running from the server, it generates a `RuntimeError: preamble calls disabled due to previous text calls` exception.

What is causing this, and why does it not happen on my PC?

Comment: Maybe LaTeX can not be started properly. Can you run LaTeX on the command line on a minimal file? Also it might be that you installed LaTeX on the server, but it is not collable from within your Python script, maybe due to a missing path in the PATH environment variable. If all this is working properly, please get PyX to dump the commands passed to LaTeX by `text.set("Latex", texdebug="pyxlatex")`, which will create a file `pyxlatex.tex`. Try to run it using latex on the command line ...

Comment: @wobsta I finally solved the issue by installing the texlive-fonts-extra package